# Reference for cdh topology

Tags: grothendieck-topology, descent, nisnevich-topology

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a proper surjective morphism over some base scheme $S$ of finite type, suppose $f$ restricts to an isomorphism over some open $U$ of $X$, we also suppose both $X$ and $Y$ are integral for simplicity.

I guess now $f$ is a covering for the cdh-topology. Now is there anyway to get an injection
$$0\rightarrow \mathrm{Pic}^{\tau}_{Y/S}\rightarrow \mathrm{Pic}^{\tau}_{X/S}$$.

By the way is $\mathbb{G}_m$ a sheaf for the cdh-topology?

Could anyone give me a good reference for cdh topology treated in a general way instead serving only for motivic cohomology?

Comment: i made a very stupid mistake, now i have editted my question.

Comment: Are you sure that all (non-generic) points of $Y$ lift to $X$?

Comment: no, thanks for that point. i guess i need f to be surjective. i have edited my question

Comment: I believe that a proper generically surjective morphism is always surjective. Yet it not clear that above any point $y$ of $Y$ there is an isomorphic point $x$ of $X$ (so, the question is whether the field for $x$ is isomorphic to that for $y$ and not just a finite extension of it).

Comment: now i am confused. According to wiki page for h-topology, this is just the example of cdh-cover given there

Comment: In the Wikipedia article, the cdh-covering is the proper map $p:Y\to X$ together with the closed immersion $e:A\to X$. This way, each point of $X$ has a point lying above it with isomorphic residue field.

Comment: won't $f（X-U）\rightarrow Y$ give such a closed immersion? Note: i stick to my old notation, which is opposite to yours,  X--〉Y

Comment: (Sorry, I used the notation of the Wikipedia article) The point is that the closed subset over which $f$ is not an isomorphism is a necessary part of the covering. In particular, the exact sequence you are asking for should have $\operatorname{Pic}(Y)\to\operatorname{Pic}(X)\oplus\operatorname{Pic}(Z)$ with $Z$ the complement of $U$.

Comment: @Matthias and Mikhail   thank both of you for clarifying the definition! Do you happen to know some good reference for cdh topology?

Comment: Sorry, I only know references related to motivic cohomology or homotopy, nothing in a general way...